# \llap (or \rlap) at the beginning of an indented paragraph

Tags: indentation, tex-core, paragraphs

If I use a `\llap{text}` command at the beginning of an indented paragraph, the `text` is not indented and is put on the line above the paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\parindent=2cm

\llap{x}Hello

H\llap{x}ello

\end{document}
```

Using the code above, I get the `x` above and far too the left, relative to the `H` in the first case, but I get the correct result in the second case (the `x` is just to the left of the `e`).

[image: Screenshot of the above code]

**How can I get the `x` just to the left of the `H`?**

I tried putting a `vphantom{X}` just before the `\llap` to force the paragraph to start, but that didn't change the result at all.

Comment: you need `\leavevmode` as `\llap` is `\hbox` not `\mbox` The supported LaTeX syntax is `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` which does not have this surprise.

Comment: You can also do `\hspace*{0pt}\llap{x}Hello`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Except `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` is `\rlap`, while `\makebox[0pt][r]{...}` is `\llap`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`\llap` is not a LaTeX box command and does not start a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\parindent=2cm

\makebox[0pt][r]{x}Hello

H\makebox[0pt][r]{x}ello

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can also use

```
\indent\llap{x}Hello
```